# subprocess error in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, popen

I am trying to run a praat file from python itself with subprocess but python(subprocess) can't seem to find the directory. I don't understand why since when I run the command in terminal, it works perfectly fine. Cant anyone guide me to where I am going wrong? 
This is the subprocess code

```
import silex
import subprocess as sb
cmd_line = raw_input()
args = shlex.split(cmd_line)
p = sb.Popen(args)
```

When I run it with the input

```
Praat /Users/admirmonteiro/tmp/tmp.praat
```

this is the error that I get :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/admirmonteiro/anaconda/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/Users/admirmonteiro/anaconda/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

As mentioned, I run the commands and they run fine in the terminal.
I have also tried to run subprocess.call but the same error occurs. I have also tried with with shell=True as an argument but that also outputs the same error.
Please Help !

Comment: What does `which Praat` return when run from the shell manually?

Comment: If I type it in by itself, it opens the app. If I open it with the file as I mentioned, it runs the file which returns another file. Which if I do that in terminal it works.

Comment: Also when I run subprocess.call([Praat"]) , I got the error : call(["Praat"],shell=True)
/bin/sh: Praat: command not found
127                                                                                                                          this makes no sense because when I run Praat in terminal, it works. I am confused .

Comment: Try with the full path to Praat

Comment: Also your script don't make any sense, you read a command from the command line and run it? Why not just run the command to begin with instead

Comment: I did run the with the whole path of Praat and it did work. I did run also with the script and it worked just fine, the thing is that I am outputting in python as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type the following in the shell to get the full path of the `Praat`application.

```
whereis Praat
```

Then use the full path in you python program.

Comment: note: `type Praat` (`whence`, `where`, `which`) or `command -v Praat` might be more useful here, to find the full path to the executable. See [What is the unix command to find out what executable file corresponds to a given command?](http://superuser.com/q/351889/13868)

Comment: related: [Why not use “which”? What to use then?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85249/1321)

Comment: According to man pages, `whereis` checks the standard binary directories (...) printing out the paths of any it finds, `which` will locate a program in the user's path.  Therefore `which` is probably a better choice, since the OP said he was able to run it in the command line.

Comment: Read the links I've provided (really, the answers there are very thorough). Use `type Praat` if you run the command interactively in a shell or `command -v Praat` if it is in a script. It is more likely that `type` will show the actual executable that will be run than `whereis`.